# How can I blink a LED differently when I press a toggle button?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to blink a LED according to press of toggle button. If I press the first toggle switch the first time, LED blinks at 5 Hz, when I press the toggle button for the second time, LED blink at 6 Hz and when I press the third time, LED turns off.

I tried using the program below, but It's not working as I wanted.

```
// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 7;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  6;      // the number of the LED pin
// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;  

// variable for reading the pushbutton status
void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
   int x=0; 
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Serial.print(x);
  // check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH &&  x==0) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    Serial.print(x);
  } else {
    // turn LED off:
    x = x+1;
  }
  if (buttonState == HIGH && x==1) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); 
    delay(2000);
     Serial.print(x);

  } else {
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    x = x+1;
  }
  if (buttonState == HIGH && x==2) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(3000);
     Serial.print(x);
  } else {
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    x = x+1;

  }
  if (buttonState == HIGH && x==3) {
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    x = 0;
  }
}
```

When I use this code it works for first case that is LED blinks at 1000 ms delay, but if I toggle switch it again works for first condition. How can I make it to execute second condition i.e. to blink at delay of 2000 ms?

Comment: Your condition logic is kinda off here. Did you try to debug this and see which "if" branches are getting executed and what happens to `x`?

Comment: 50Hz and 60Hz, are you sure these frequencies are correct? Is a bit high for a led.

Comment: sorry it's 5 and 6 I didn't focus on that

Comment: The correct way is to use hardware peripheral timers and remove the tight coupling between button presses and delays. This will only work if the user keeps the button pressed for more than 2 seconds, which is crappy.

Comment: can I do  debounce  an interrupt trigger?

Comment: @NikhilR Yes you can, set a timer in the interrupt and when the timer finishes, check the button state, if the button is pressed, there was a edge. Bouncing would result in multiple starts of the timer, so only the last will be detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly this is your circuit. I tried this circuit and code and worked for me. I used interrupt for checking button state. And millis calculation is simple.

Frequency = 1 / Period

Period = Ton + Toff

6Hz = 1000  millis / T => T = 166 millis

166 = Ton + Toff (for %50 duty cycle Ton=Toff) => Ton = Toff = 83 millis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdjLH.png)

```
const int ledPin = 13;
const int buttonPin = 2;
int state = -1;
bool willLightOn = false;

unsigned long currentDelay = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin), changeState, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  if(state % 3 == 0) { //6Hz 
    currentDelay = 83;
    willLightOn = true;
  } else if (state % 3 == 1) { //5Hz
    currentDelay = 100;
    willLightOn = true;
  } else if (state % 3 == 2) { //LED off
    currentDelay = 0;
    willLightOn = false;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

  currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= currentDelay && willLightOn) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(ledPin));
    } 
}

void changeState() {
  state++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a global state of the application. This state is where you remember if you are blinking at 50hz/60hz/off. Then you can use a switch to do the right thing.

Then you check if the button is pressed and change the application state.

See my example below:

```
// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 7;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  6;      // the number of the LED pin
// variables will change:
int applicationState = 0;  
bool lightOn = true;

int currentDelay = 1000;

unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

// variable for reading the pushbutton status
void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
        applicationState++;
        if(applicationState >= 3) {
            applicationState = 0;
        }
        delay(100);
    }

    switch(applicationState){
        case 0:
            currentDelay = 1000;
            lightOn = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            currentDelay = 2000;
            lightOn = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            lightOn = false;
            break;
    }


    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= currentDelay && lightOn) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(ledPin));
    }      
}
```

I hope you understand what I try to say and demo with the example code.

Comment: this doesn't work like I wanted, it follows the same blink pattern for every press of the button

Comment: @NikhilR The button must be pressed at the time the ledPin switch from LOW to HIGH. (That is because the uC is sleeping for 2000 or 4000 whatever units you use here)

Comment: yeah, how can I use millis() instead of delay?

Comment: I changed the code, this should work. The only thing is that you should hold the button too long, because then you going to switch constantly between the states.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your logic checks 3 times for the value of x in a single loop.
Below code toggles light whenever x is greater than zero. x's value is changed when button is pressed.

But there is a big problem here: If button is pressed when there's something else going on in the processor or it is sleeping (like the long delays you want to use), it may be ignored. So you better study interrupts and implement this behavior using them.

```
if (x > 0)
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(1000 * x);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
if (buttonState == HIGH)
{
    x++;
    if (x > 3)
        x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `delay(1000*x)` and remove all the `switch()-case`?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 oh it's even better. fixing that

Comment: As far as understood, the blinking should keep going till the next button press?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 thanks for the heads up. I tried to read the code OP provided and assumed that wasn't the case but you are right. I hopefully converted it to suit that request.

Comment: Yes you're right it should going on the rate of the present delay until next press @12431234123412341234123

Answer (score 0):

Your code can not work:

1. You do need to check if the button state changes, detect when there is a edge. And make sure you detect a single edge only once.
2. You must repeat the blinking it in a loop till the button is pressed, then you can change the frequency.
3. You must check the button while you sleep, otherwise your program do not recognize when you press the button.

To make it work, you must change the complete program.

```
#define BLINK_SLEEP_TIME <some value> // insert value for 16.6666ms

//return 1 after a positive edge
bool button_read(void)
{
  static bool lastState=1; //set this to 1, so that a pressed button at startup does not trigger a instant reaction
  bool state = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(state != lastState)
    {
      state=lastState;
      return state;
    }
 return 0;
}

//Blink the LED with a given period, till button is pressed
//Times are in x*16.666ms or x/60Hz
//At least one time should be more than 0
void blink(uint8_t ontime, uint8_t offtime) 
{
  while(1)
  {
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<ontime;i++)
    {
      led_setOn();
      delay(BLINK_SLEEP_TIME);
      if(button_read())
      {
        return;
      }
    }
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<offtime;i++)
    {
      led_setOff();
      delay(BLINK_SLEEP_TIME);
      if(button_read())
      {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

const uint8_t time_table[][]=
{
  {0,50},//LED is off
  {6,6}, //LED blinks with 5Hz, 60Hz/2/6=5Hz
  {5,5}, //LED blinks with 6Hz, 60Hz/2/5=6Hz
}

void endless(void)
{
  uint8_t i=0;
  for(;;)
    {
      i++;
      if(i>2)
      {
        i=0;
      }
      blink(time_table[i][0],time_table[i][1]);
    }
}
```

A better approach would be to use a hardware PWM-Module and change the values after a edge on the button.

Comment: How can I call led_setOn(); and led_setOff(); here?

Comment: @NikhilR Either replace it with `digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);`/`digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);` (bad), or write a macro or function for it (better). When you use `digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);` directly, you don't see if it turns the led ON or OFF (high or low active).

Comment: Hey why am I getting an error as exit status 1
'time' was not declared in this scope for this   for(uint8_t i=0;i<offtime || !time ;i++)

Comment: @NikhilR Because it does not work this way, it was left over from some edits. Please try to understand the code before copy pasting it.